# can i modify canvas outside Phaser's update or create functions?

Tags: phaser

can i create/change/destroy game objects (i.e. sprite, text) outside "create" function or "update" game-loop?

i'm working on a multiplayer game with nodejs and socket.io, and following is my former codes:

```
function create() {...}
function update() {...}
//the following codes are outside any state object
var socket = io.connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx");
socket.on("init", function(data) {
    game.add.sprite(0, 0, data.background);
    game.add.text(0, 0, data.title);
});
```

neither the sprite nor the text displayed correctly (sometimes display a "X" image)

then i move these codes to update function and it works fine:

```
var initData;
function update() {
    if (initData) {
        game.add.sprite(0, 0, initData.background);
        game.add.text(0, 0, initData.title);
        initDate = null;
    }
}
var socket = io.connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx");
socket.on("init", function(data) {
    initDate = data;
});
```

same thing happens when i wrote `title.setText("new title")` in `socket.on` function

so, is there any way i can directly modify canvas objects in socket's callback function ? sorry for my poor english :)